# ACF Wysiwyg Editor Image srcset for responsive images

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, images, responsive, wysiwyg, html5

I cannot find a way to generate srcset for images added inside Wysiwyg Editor field of Advanced Custom Field (ACF) plugin. Obviously, i know how to generate WordPress image srcset using:

wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($attachment_id);

function, as described at WordPress codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_srcset/

But my real problem is to figure out most efficient way to get image srcset for images added inside ACF Wysiwyg Editor as the way my website is structured there is too much content inside my Wysiwyg Editor like text, images, videos and different heading tags.

Also, all the images added inside WordPress default Wysiwyg Editor is showing image srcset properly.

It's just that ACF Wysiwyg Editor is not supporting this. Any pointers to add efficient filter/hooks will be really helpful.

Comment: You're going to need a hefty dose of ACF knowledge here, or a feature request to the ACF developers

Comment: Voted to reopen. srcsets for image tags are added with a filter on `the_content`. Doing this on arbitrary HTML is possible with the `wp_make_content_images_responsive()` function and has nothing to do with ACF.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, the function just worked perfectly and has solved my issue